# Avoiding boost::python::extract<int>

Tags: python, c++, boost, boost-python

I am running a rather simple task that is being handicapped by the use of *boost::python::extract*. In short I have a very large python list containing only integers. I need to pass those integer values to a C++ map using the find function. In order to do the hash using the contents of the array I need to convert those contents (a python list object) into an int. I can guarantee from my workflow that only ints will be passed to this list

Because my array is so large I have looked into multithreading but it seems that whenever I have to threads try to read from the array and use the *boost::python::extract* function I get a SegFault.

I am wondering if there is an alternative to *boost::python::extract* or a better representation than *boost::python::list*. One in which C++ can explicitly tell that the contents are ints without me having to step through and convert each element one at a time (which currently takes several seconds).

Thank you

Comment: Could you maybe dump your large list to a file or a memory mapped file and then C++ code load it and go from there? It is a silly hack that just might work.

Comment: Thanks! This was substantially better than my current approach. I guess sometimes the simpler solutions can work best. I am curious though if there is any way I could have done this and kept the data in memory...

Comment: What about making that list a numpy array, and use the numpy module shipped with boost::python?